# save logs in UIAutomation Tests in text file

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I want to save logs created in text file. When we run any script for Automation, .plist is created in specified folder of Logging tab in instruments.
How can I make this conversion or is there any other way to save log messages?
Any help on this subject, will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch Instruments from the command line and you'll get the logs in text plain. You can also use `UIALogger` class to add your own messages.